# Why the Http Post Response is different in Console and Network response tab?

Tags: angular, http-post, response

I am working on angular2, I am having a problem with HTTP post response. My endpoint should return boolean and is returning response correctly in chrome's Network response tab but when I have logged response in the console, it shows the empty object. I could not figure it out that why the response is different in network and console tabs. 
Here is my code:

```
this._buybackApi.checkValueUnique(checkValueData, CheckValueFormData).subscribe(
    (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.checkUniqueRes = response;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
        console.log(this.checkUniqueRes);
    }
);

Code in api file:

public checkValueUnique(uniqueValue: models.UniqueValue, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkValueUniqueWithHttpInfo(uniqueValue, extraHttpRequestParams)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            if (response.status === 204) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return response.json() || {};
            }
        });
}
public checkValueUniqueWithHttpInfo(uniqueValue: models.UniqueValue, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<Response> {
    const path = this.basePath + '/IsValueUnique';

    let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
    let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON()); 
    // verify required parameter 'uniqueValue' is not null or undefined
    if (uniqueValue === null || uniqueValue === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter uniqueValue was null or undefined when calling checkValueUnique.');
    }
    // to determine the Content-Type header
    let consumes: string[] = [
        '*/*'
    ];

    // to determine the Accept header
    let produces: string[] = [
        'application/json'
    ];

    // authentication (basicAuth) required
    // http basic authentication required
    if (this.configuration.username || this.configuration.password) {
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(this.configuration.username + ':' + this.configuration.password));
    }    

    let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        headers: headers,
        body: extraHttpRequestParams         
    });

    if (extraHttpRequestParams) {
        requestOptions = (<any>Object).assign(requestOptions, extraHttpRequestParams);
    }

    return this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the body of your function checkValueUnique(checkValueData, CheckValueFormData)?

Comment: @SamanGholami Just updated my question for checkValueUnique()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided your return statement from `checkValueUnique` will print one of three values:

1. `undefined` if it's a 204 response status code.
2. The response body if it's a valid JSON object.
3. An empty object `{}` if `response.json()` is undefined.

You're getting `{}` because the call to `response.json()` is undefined.  You say that the response returns a boolean.  A boolean value (true or false) in the body of a response is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, it helped.